# How to view the all command in man page 8

Tags: command-line, manpage

I try to view all the commands in man page 8 using terminal by this code `man man 8`, but it only shows man(1).

So I tried another method `man 8 man` but it says `No manual entry for man in section 8 See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.`

How can I view all commands in man page 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this will get you a list of every man page in section 8:

```
apropos -s 8 . | less
```

The option `-s 8` restricts the search to section 8.  Since the specified regex `.` matches anything, this should produce all the pages.

Comment: "apropos  -s 8 . | less" here  dot(.) worked fine .but i checked another method "man 8  ." it shows  "No manual entry for . in section 8"  Why dot worked man

Comment: @P.G.Krish `apropos` and `man` are two different commands.  `man` expects a command name as an argument.  By contrast, `apropos` expects a regular expression as an argument.